# wordpress onepager - redirect all pages to frontpage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Anyone have simple method for one pager wordpress site? I mean redirecting all pages to frontpage. I dont want to delete all template files and meta nofollow is too simple. Any ideas, plugins, htaccess tricks? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in your functions.php:-

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_page_redirect', PHP_INT_MAX);
function my_page_redirect(){
   if( !is_front_page() ) {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     setTimeout(function() { 
        document.location = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>"; }, 500
     );
</script>
<?php
   }
}
```